# How can we trigger act_window action from on_change function?

Tags: python, action, onchange, odoo

I have a selection widget with several items that happen to be names of different models, on selecting a model, I want to trigger an `act_window` based on that model so how can we trigger an action from `on_change` function?

As far as I'm aware, it only reads `"value"`, `"domain"` and `"warning"`. I want similar functionality to a button `"type=object"` where we can simply return the action and everything works fine but I'm having no luck reproducing this from an `on_change` method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger window action from on_change function. But your button can return an action.
please check this post: [Method return value to call another form in OpenERP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634031/method-return-value-to-call-another-form-in-openerp/12634259#12634259)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm aware of returning an action from a button's method but I have a list of about 15 items that have an associated view to them, it doesn't make much sense to have 15 buttons on the form, is there a better way to do this? Maybe a one2many list...

Comment: In one of the sales wizard (make invoice), they trigger a workflow by `wf_service = netsvc.LocalService('workflow')` isn't there an eqivalent for an action?

Comment: I didnt told to add 15buttons. you need to add a selection which select any one of the view and in your button you can generate the domain, context and every other needed attributes that needed for the new view

Comment: I did think about that and I think I will go for that approach but it would still be nice to know how to trigger an action from python without a button 'return'. I could use that knowledge elsewhere, its very unclear from the documentation about openerp's workflow, how do actions get recognised and triggered etc...Thank you for your help regardless, I really appreciate it.