# how to fill tree in default get in openerp

Tags: odoo, displayobject

I have an object hs.code which has two fields name and code. I want to display all the rows in hs.code in a tab on the sales order. hs.codes has nothing to do with the sales order. they just need to be displayed on every sale order by default. hs.codes should also be editable on the sales order. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, when hs.code is not a part of sales order then you can not display hs.code rows on sales order form. You can do by create a button on sales order to call method with return value to call hs.code form. see this : 
[Method return value to call another form in OpenERP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634031/method-return-value-to-call-another-form-in-openerp)